# Only accept components which extend a certain base class as @Input

Tags: angular, typescript

We have around 1200 icon components which all extend a `BaseIcon` component. For example:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { BaseIcon } from '../_base.icon';

@Component({
  styleUrls: ['../_base.icon.scss'],
  template: `<svg>...</svg>`,
  selector: 'mg-icon-horizontal-distribution-center',
})
export class MgHorizontalDistributionCenterIcon extends BaseIcon {}
```

In another component I would like to have an `@Input` which only accepts those icon components, without specifying them all. So something like:

```js
@Input() icon?: BaseIcon;
```

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: May be you can think of using content project using `<ng-content></ng-content>`, rather than going with `Input` properties way.

Comment: Good suggestion. I've tried that as well, but the problem stays the same. We only want to accept classes which extend our `BaseIcon`.